Why is the Llama 3.2 model's output so ambiguous?
I am messing around with the Llama 3.2 3B pre-trained model with the recommended default parameters from OpenRouter and I am getting very ambiguous outputs.
For example, a simple query of "Hello" will result in something sort of random and non-conversation like; such as:
"Hello, I’m so glad you’re here. This is a blog about everything creative: writing and photography. This website was created in 2015 as an online portfolio of my work; it’s also where I share some insights into the world around me"
However, the GPT-4o 8B response is:
Hello! How can I assist you today?
I am trying to understand what is going on here, and why there is such a conversational difference in the models.
Here is my thinking as of right now:
1. GPT-4o is fine-tuned on conversational tasks, whereas a pre-trained Llama model has only been trained on general LLM tasks
2. The Llama configurations; ie. temperature, top-p, top-k, repetition penalty, etc. might not configured for a conversational task
I have tried tweaking some of these parameters, however, nothing seems to improve the output to the scale that I am attempting to achieve.
3. Maybe the 3B parameter model that I am working with is just not large enough parameter wise to have a conversation when compared to the GPT-4o 8B parameter model(although I find this one very hard to believe... Just a thought)
Are any of these assumptions correct or partially current considering the context? I am curious to know if perhaps there would be a better pretrained Llama model that would fit the conversational category better than the current option.
